# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

> View page

```
<form action="{{url('/deleteUser/'.$value->id)}}" method="POST" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
```

> Route

```
Route::get('/deleteUser/{id}','UserController@destroy');
```

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64tLT.png)

Comment: Your form says it's a POST request but your route says it will only allow GET request. You need to keep them in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Change `method="POST"`into `method="GET"` or `Route::get`into `Route::post`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('/deleteUser/{id}','UserController@destroy');
```